How to use parallel: matrix in gitlab.ci to run multiple maven profiles
Curious if I can do something like what is below, essentially use parallel matrix to tack -P flags to the maven script. Is there a way to use parallel matrix to add different maven profiles and run the scripts in parallel? Or is there another way to do this without having  the jobs separated? I want them coupled together in the pipeline.
test-e2e:
  stage: test
  script:
    - |
      mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - VERSION: [-Ptest1,-Ptest2]


Why do you need those profiles? What is the purpose of them? Can you show your pom file? Which Maven version, JDK versio etc. do you use?

You can use the value specified in matrix as a regular environment variable:
test-e2e:
  stage: test
  script:
    - |
      mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test ${VERSION}
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - VERSION: [-Ptest1,-Ptest2]

Note that this is just a syntactic sugar to reduce code duplication, so there is no special coupling between jobs.
